# Unknown border lines added to product rows

Tags: html, css, wordpress

If you check the last 3 product rows here; *Link deleted* There have been weird vertical lines added to each product. I can't even figure it out in HTML/CSS code.

You can check the screenshot here: *Link deleted*

May I know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the text inside the `span` tag. Since you have rotate option for span bg image even that text is rotated. Remove that text if it is not really necessary.

```
<span class="onsale">Tilbud!</span>
```